# filter on criteria then copy and paste at bottom of same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, autofilter

I'm new to VBA and after much searching, i can't get the code working correctly. I am trying to filter/select anything which has the value 313 in column B AND the values 1 OR 2 in column C then copy all the relevant rows with the data from all columns (A-N) at the bottom of the same worksheet. The worksheet does not have a set number of rows and 313 is not always in the same set of cells. I have tried the following but the code seems to be pasting in 'A2' rather than the selection at the bottom. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim filterRange As range
Dim copyRange As range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")

ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

lastRow = ws1.range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set filterRange = ws1.range("A1:N" & lastRow)


Set copyRange = ws1.range("A2:N" & lastRow)

 filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="313"
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=1", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=2"


lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
  ws1.Cells(lastRow, 1).Select
ws1.Paste


 ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see where it is copying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must:

- change `xlAnd` into `xlOr`
- increase `lastRow` of 1 to reference the cell to paste in
- use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to select filtered cells (if any!)

try his

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        With .Range("A1:N" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="313"
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="2"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then 'count visible cells in column "A" other than the header
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)
            End If
        End With

         .AutoFilterMode = False
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much this works perfectly, just what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that because you are redefining the last row after a filter, using `xlUp` will miss the last row since it may be hidden in the filter. I would suggest using

```
lastRow = lastRow + 1
```

since you already have the last row of the range defined and you just want to past one row below that.

Your second filter, by the way, will filter on nothing because no cell will be both equal to 1 and equal to 2. Not sure what you want there. In any case, like I said in my comment, I don't believe you are copying anything, so you will need

```
filterRange.Copy
```

after the filter. I am not sure I would recommend copying and pasting like this, but I am going to try to just modify your code instead of rewriting it.

Also, I don't believe that

```
Set copyRange = ws1.range("A2:N" & lastRow)
```

is needed at all and can be deleted.

This is what I have in full

```
Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
lastRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set filterRange = ws1.Range("A1:N" & lastRow)
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="313"
filterRange.Copy
lastRow = lastRow + 1
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 1).Select
ws1.Paste
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```